# Rewriting the matrix $a_{i, j} = \min\{i, j\} - \frac{i j}{n + 1}$ using matrix products.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have the following matrix,

$$
\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}: \  a_{i, j} = \min\{i, j\} - \frac{i j}{n+1}
$$

and I was wondering if it was possible to rewrite it in terms of the vector,

$$
\mathbf{[n]} = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ \vdots \\ n
    \end{pmatrix}
$$.

**So far...**

... I notice that

$$
\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 &\ldots \\
1 & 2 & 2  &\ldots \\
1 & 2 & 3 &\ldots\\
\vdots &  & & \ddots
\end{pmatrix} - \frac{1}{n+1} \mathbf{[n]} \mathbf{[n]}^{\prime}
$$

but, after looking into its LU decomposition, I could not work out if that first matrix $\min\{i, j\}$ can be written in terms of $\mathbf{[n]}$.

Comment: Why do you think it can be expressed in terms of $[\mathbf n]$? I think it's easier and clearer to express $A$ as $L(I-\frac{ee^T}{n+1})L^T$ where $e$ is the vector of ones and $L$ is the lower triangular matrix of ones.

Comment: That is definitely an option. I was thinking $\mathbf{[n]}$ would be easier but your solution seems more helpful. Follow up: can $L$ be written in terms of $e$ or another vector?